# How to add log in Jitsi prosody plugin lua files

Tags: logging, webrtc, jitsi, jitsi-meet, prosody-im

I am trying to add some log in Jitsi meet prosody module Lua files. e.g : in
mod_muc_allowners.Lua file. How to add logs in these lua files and where can I check this?

[mod_muc_allowners.Lua](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/resources/prosody-plugins/mod_muc_allowners.lua)

[mod_av_moderation_component.lua](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/827e8201d413f655bf8b81673153995a89408585/resources/prosody-plugins/mod_av_moderation_component.lua#L289) in this file, suppose I want to check if this method is called or not. How can I check that.

```
function occupant_affiliation_changed(event)
```

also, are these Lua files run from the Prosody server? is there any connection in Jicofo for added prosody modules in jitsi meet?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

If you closely look at the code you will find in **73rd** line of **mod_muc_allowners.lua** that :
`module:log('debug', 'skip allowners for non-auth user subdomain:%s room_name:%s', subdomain, room_name);`

Here, you can just set the log level in the 1st parameter and log message in the 2nd parameter. and other parameters are only required depending on any variable you indicated by "%s" in the 2nd parameter.
you can simply write any log message anywhere and catch the logs from the server by tailing prosody.log in the server while running a conference.

and for any query, you can simply post on its community where you can seek more attention if your topic is about jitsi. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Nafiul, yes, got the answer in the Jitsi community also.